# SSRS dynamic data retrieved from another dataset

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I want to get data(dynamic)according to the data in another dataset and put the result in textbox of the different dataset.
Right now, the data I get is static and I tried to use many expressions but no avail. 
Problem lies in editing textbox expression. Since I am getting data from different dataset, it always ask me to have dataset aggregate function in my expression. If I specified the dataset from where I am getting the data, then, I cannot make it dynamic- and i get the undesired result.
And another way out that I attempted is merging the data sets into one rather than having multiples and use it only. But unsuccessful.
How can I make it work to get the result that I want.

By the way, the textbox and the tables are in different scope. I have tried to combine them in one scope too.

Please shed a light on it. 
Thanks in advance!